# Select certain number of records for batch processing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Hi is it possible using Entity Framework and/or linq to select a certain number of rows? For example i want to select rows 0 - 500000 and assign these records to the List VariableAList object, then select rows 500001 - 1000000 and assign this to the List VariableBList object, etc. etc.

Where the Numbers object is like ID,Number,DateCreated, DateAssigned, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `.Take(int)` and `.Skip(int)` methods

```
using (YourEntities db = new YourEntities())
{
    var VariableAList = db.Numbers
        .Take(500000);

    var VariableBList = db.Numbers
        .Skip(500000)
        .Take(500000);
}
```

You may want to be wary of the size of these lists in memory.

**Note:** You also may need an `.OrderBy` clause prior to using `.Skip` or `.Take`--I vaguely remember running into this problem in the past.

Comment: Cheers this is just what i'm after, was playing around with take but hadnt thought of combining it with skip! Do you happen to know what is a good size (in terms of memory) to use?

Comment: That's a bit subjective depending on your hardware, etc. But, using `IQueryable`'s whenever possible can help, and that's going to depend on how you're using these records. Running your own benchmarks might give you an idea whether or not 500,000 records in your environment represents a significant memory hit